# Как задать символ кавычек

Tags: ios, objective-c

Я пытаюсь создать программу которая будет искать символы в тексте если они есть в массиве, например

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" ", @",", @".", @"!", 
@"?", @")", nil];
```

но как быть, если я хочу так же добавить в массив символ кавычек, на запись типа

```
@""",
```

выдается ошибка

Answer (score 4):

Экранируйте кавычку знаком "\". Вот так:

```
@"\""
```

Получится:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@" ", @",", @".", @"!",
                  @"?", @")", @"\"", nil];
```